# Save data between application execution in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to save data between application execution and compare the old data with new data and proceed with the other implementation. Data is the result of a query. I need to check on the count of old data and new data. if the count is more then I need to consider the newly added data.

What best method I can use to implement this.

Comment: Do you want  to compare old data and new data ? And  will save the unmatched  new data. ? Are you Tamil?

Comment: Please give some more details like what type of data, where to store etc.

Comment: please describe old data and new data?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities, depending on your requirements, the size of the data and your skills. You could save the data for example:

- in a well-known file
- in a database
- as session state

What would be preferable is not obvious from your description.